# Wordpress- where to place custom log files

Tags: wordpress, logging

In WordPress, where is the best place to put custom log files for my plugin?
I want to create a directory in the log folder upon activation of the plugin.

Comment: If you don't care if they are potentially over-written on update, you can just keep the log files within the plugin folder. You could also place it within wp-content if you want them to persist. Both of these options require the parent directory to be writable by wordpress or apache.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of putting it there but didn't know if that was a bad idea!